# Selenium, SimpleBrowser.WebDriver cannot pull data from Frame

Tags: selenium, xpath, web-scraping, frame

I am trying to pull results from inside the Frame, but when I check the Page Source on VS, the frame I am trying to pull content from cannot be displayed. Selenium cannot see inside the frame so final xpath doesn't work. I can't see what I am missing.

PS: containerNo is a string and value is GFSSEA1610, Just made it up for test.

```
            IWebDriver driver = new SimpleBrowserDriver();
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://aplinfo.apl.com/tracking/");
                IWebElement query = driver.FindElement(By.Id("trace"));
                query.SendKeys(containerNo);
                query.Submit();
                var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
                wait.Until(d => d.Url.StartsWith("http://homeport.apl.com/gentrack/", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
                driver.FindElement(By.Name("bodyframe"));
                driver.SwitchTo().Frame("bodyframe");
                result = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/table")).Text;
```

Comment: Share your html and the error message you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it as follows:

```
IWebDriver Frame = driver.SwitchTo().Frame("bodyframe");
```

or

```
string frameHTML= driver.SwitchTo().Frame("bodyframe").PageSource;
```